# Enabling SSH version 1

Tags: ssh, fedora-16

I need to enable SSH version one on my server for testing reasons. I understand all the risks, but still need to be able to do it. I have edited the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file to remove the `#` before the line `Protocol 2,1` and changed it to `Protocol 1`, yet it still gives me an error saying the `major versions differ` when I log on.

Is there something I am leaving out here? I’m using Fedora 16 to connect to an SSH server on another Fedora 16 machine with the command `ssh -1 <ip-address>` to connect. Also, my `~/.ssh/config` file is empty.

Answer (score 5):

You need to edit the ssh**d**_config file to configure the server.